# Why does my search button not work on specific browsers

Tags: html

The code below, which serves as a search button, seems to work only on Chrome. I have tested the search button in Firefox, Firefox Developer Edition, Internet Explorer and Edge (All of which are on the latest version).

`<input type="search" name="q" id="searchBarMain" onsearch="search(event)" class="">`

I feel like there is something key I am missing which I cannot find anywhere. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

The OnSearch event is not supported: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsearch.asp

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you know what an alternative would be?

Comment: You'd probably need to use a button that utilises OnClick, or a form that utilises OnSubmit

Comment: Weird, it is supposed to work in Safari, but it isn't.